# Drupal and apache rewrites

Tags: .htaccess, proxies

I'm just migrating a site that has a proxy pass in the vhost config like the following.

```
ProxyPass /n/ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:80/n/
ProxyPassReverse /n/ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:80/n/
```

I need to replicate that in the drupal .htaccess file as I don't have direct access to the hosting as we're using a fully managed drupal solution. I have tried the following but it does not work, when I navigate to the drupal site /n I just get a 404.

```
RewriteRule /n/?$ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:80/n/ [P]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that [P] requires mod_proxy to be enabled:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /n/(.*)$ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:80/n/$1 [P]
```